# Regex for match url in Django

Tags: python, django, regex

I'm trying to match this url with a regexp in django/python (old liferay urls)

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/documents/34105/35593/prova+(1)+(1).jpg/da459266-ab36-faf1-726d-fc989385b0bd
```

but I cannot decode the filename...

This is the regexp that I use:

```
documents/(?P<repo>[0-9]{5,10})/(?P<folder>[0-9]{5,10})/(?P<filename>[])/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)
```

This is the Pythex [link](https://pythex.org/?regex=documents%2F(%3FP%3Crepo%3E%5B0-9%5D%7B5%2C10%7D)%2F(%3FP%3Cfolder%3E%5B0-9%5D%7B5%2C10%7D)%2F(%3FP%3Cfilename%3E%5B%5D)%2F(%3FP%3Cuuid%3E%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B)&test_string=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8080%2Fdocuments%2F34105%2F35593%2Fprova%2B(1)%2B(1).jpg%2Fda459266-ab36-faf1-726d-fc989385b0bd&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
documents/(?P<repo>\d+)/(?P<folder>\d+)/(?P<filename>[^/]+)/(?P<uuid>[^/]+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/2uOy59/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  documents/               'documents/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<repo>                        group and capture to (?P=repo):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of (?P=repo)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<folder>               group and capture to (?P=folder):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of (?P=folder)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<filename>             group and capture to (?P=filename):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of (?P=filename)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<uuid>                  group and capture to (?P=uuid):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^/]+                    any character except: '/' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of (?P=uuid)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect!